# Is Romberg integration method implemented as weighted function values numerically correct?

Tags: numeric, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, numerical-analysis, numerical-computing

I have to integrate expression `f(x) * g(x)` for many different functions `f` but just one `g`.

I want to integrate it as sum of weighted values of `f(x) * g(x)` instead of calculating the table.  Note that in Python I may write:

```
sum(w[i] * f(x[i]) * g(x[i]) for i in range(2 ** k + 1))
```

as:

```
wg = [w[i] * g(x[i]) for i in range(2 ** k + 1)]
sum(wg[i] * f(x[i]) for i in range(2 ** k + 1))
```

where `w[i]` are weights of function values used by the Romberg method which may be calculated like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import romb

w = romb(np.eye(2 ** k + 1))
```

Is such implementation of Romberg method safe?

(The question has been also asked at CS: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35469/is-romberg-integration-method-implemented-as-weighted-function-values-numericall)

Comment: Consider posting at [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) if you don't get enough attention here. If you decide to proceed, please, delete this post or at least cross-link them.

Comment: @AntonMenshov cross-linked